# SaveAs in Word Automation gives me a "This is not a valid file name" error

Tags: c#, ms-word, automation, save-as

I am trying to using Word Automation to save a document to a network drive.  I have full access to it.  I can even create directories through code on the drive.....

I created a directory on the drive using Directory.CreateDirectory with no problem.....  The issue is trying to use Word Automation to save a word document to that created directory.

the file name and path is in this format: `\\gy2k3001\Folder1\Folder2\Test.docx`

The code I use is this:

```
    Object documentPath=filepath;
    wd.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(ref documentPath, ref _oMissing, ref _oMissing, ref _oMissing, ref _oMissing, ref _oMissing, ref _oMissing, ref _oMissing, ref _oMissing, ref _oMissing, ref _oMissing, ref _oMissing, ref _oMissing, ref _oMissing, ref _oMissing, ref _oMissing);
```

where filepath  is equal to `@"\\gy2k3001\Folder1\Folder2\Test.docx"`

The error I get is this: **"This is not a valid file name.\n Try one or more of the following:\n* Check the path to make sure it was typed correctly.\n* Select a file from the list of files and folders."**

What am I doing wrong here?  Are you not able to save using network drives in automation?

I can save it fine on my local hard drive..... and like I said before I have all the permissions I need to that network directory

Comment: the path actually has two slashes in front of it.. not one.... the question didn't post it right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well.... The problem seemed to be that the server and the wd.ActiveDocument.SaveAs didn't get along too well... so I ended up saving the document elsewhere and programmatically copying the file to the destination that it needed to go to, instead of SAVING it to the destination directly

Answer (score 0):

Does the user that the program is running under have "create file" permissions on that directory? That's what it sounds like the problem is.

Just being able to create the directory may not be sufficient.

Also, what user is that program being run as? (I presume it's an EXE running under your local rights, but just checking)

Comment: I am impersonating a user through a dll

Comment: @DJBurb ~ And you're absolutely positive that the user can create files there? Might I suggest making the directory "grant users modify" (to use a non-existent command to illustrate a point)...

Comment: @drachenstern -  I think so..... when I login as the user on a different machine, I am able to create a file manually in that directory with no problem.... I don't know if that makes a difference though

Comment: that should be the defining characteristic. Go ahead and make that change _anyways_ and see what it tells you, if you can do it now or not (doubtful, but worth a check)

Comment: Well.... The problem seemed to be that the server and the wd.ActiveDocument.SaveAs didn't get along too well... so I ended up saving the document elsewhere and programmatically copying the file to the destination that it needed to go to, instead of SAVING it to the destination directly

Comment: @jcolebrand... thanks... I couldn't figure out how to answer my own question... *slaps forehead*.